# Is the support of $\rho_{AB}$ always contained in the support of $\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$?

Tags: inequality, matrix-calculus, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Given a positive unit trace Hermitian matrix, i.e. a density operator, $\rho_{AB}$ on Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B$. Consider its marginals $\rho_A$, $\rho_B$. Do we have the support of $\rho_{AB}$ always contained in the support of $\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$? If so, what is the universal constant $C$, such as the dimension, such that $C\rho_A\otimes\rho_B\geq\rho_{AB}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question: yes.

To see why, let $\Pi_A$ and $\Pi_B$ denote the projection operators onto the supports of $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ respectively, and let $1_A$ and $1_B$ denote the corresponding identity operators.
Now,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Tr}((1_A-\Pi_A)\otimes I_B)\rho) &= \operatorname{Tr}((1_A\otimes1_B)\rho) - \operatorname{Tr}((\Pi_A\otimes I_B)\rho)\\& = \operatorname{Tr}(\rho) - \operatorname{Tr}(\Pi_A\rho_A)\\& = \operatorname{Tr}(\rho) - \operatorname{Tr}(\rho_A)\\& = 0.
\end{align*}
It follows that $((1_A-\Pi_A)\otimes I_B)\rho = \rho((1_A-\Pi_A)\otimes I_B)= 0$ and thus $$(\Pi_A\otimes I_B)\rho = \rho(\Pi_A\otimes I_B)= \rho.$$
Similar analysis shows that
$$(1_A\otimes \Pi_B)\rho = \rho(1_A\otimes \Pi_B)= \rho.$$
It follows that
$$
(\Pi_A\otimes\Pi_B)\rho = \rho (\Pi_A\otimes\Pi_B) = \rho,
$$
which proves the claim that the support of $\rho$ is contained in the support of $\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$ (since $\Pi_A\otimes\Pi_B$ is the projection onto the support of $\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$).

---

I need to think more about whether or not there exists such a constant $C$.

Comment: I don't understand the last example. For $\epsilon=0$ you have $|\psi\rangle=|00\rangle$ and thus $\rho=\rho_A\otimes\rho_B$, no?

Comment: but aren't you saying that for $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, $C\rho_A\otimes\rho_B\ge\rho$ only for $C\gg1$? How is that consistent with $\rho_A\otimes\rho_B=\rho$ for $\epsilon=0$?

Comment: Ah, I made an error. My example is wrong. I've deleted it while I re-think it.

Comment: @glS I'm not sure what was wrong with the example. Why do we need the minimum constant to be a continuous function of $\epsilon$? The OP is essentially asking if we have a dimension dependent upper bound on $D_{\max}(\rho_{AB} \| \rho_A \otimes \rho_B)$ but as far as I'm aware the max relative entropy is not a continuous function.

Comment: @Rammus It seemed weird for the min constant to be discontinuous, but checking the calculation it also seems to be correct, so I guess that's just how it is. I don't really know much (if anything) about max relative entropies, so I'll trust you on that statement

Comment: @glS I guess an alternative phrasing of the problem (avoiding entropies) is to ask if we can upper bound $\|(\rho_A \otimes \rho_B)^{-1/2} \rho_{AB} (\rho_A \otimes \rho_B)^{-1/2}\|$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm and inverses are taken on the support of $\rho_A \otimes \rho_B$.